# Django 2.1 annotate count of child and grand child

Tags: django, django-2.1

I want to count how many child and grandchild each record has. These are my table structures bellow:

Records:

```
id  | name
1   | record 1
```

Posts:

```
id  | record   | title
1   | record 1 | title 1
2   | record 1 | title 2
```

Attachments:

```
   id   | post   | name
   1    | post 1 | name 1
   2    | post 1 | name 2
   3    | post 2 | name 3
```

so by this example record 1 should have

```
   children: 2
   grandchildren: 3
   total_links: 5
```

Here's my current code in my view.py:

```
records = Record.ojects.all().annotate(total_links=Count('post__id'))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
queryset = Record.ojects.all().annotate( 
                post_count=Count('post'), 
                attachment_count=Count('post__attachment'))

records = queryset.annotate(children_count= ExpressionWrapper(
                             F('post_count') + 
                             F('attachment_count'),
                             output_field=DecimalField()
))
```